# Can't run the .exe file: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm pretty sure i have the module included in the dist folder.
This is the part of the code that have this error (this is the line 7 of the test.py):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
```

after running `pyinstaller test.spec` and running the `test.exe` it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
[6488] Failed to execute script test
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use dependency walker to see if any .dll is missing, and then you look for that .dll and copy it next to the executable.

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you for the response. I figured why this problem exist, its becuase of the version of my python. I have ```python 3.6 64-bit``` when this problem shows up. Tried uninstalling and installed ```python 3.8 32-bit``` and executing the pyinstaller again and the problem solved.